# Attempting to get strings to add to an array with an addGuest method, but not adding anything

Tags: java

I'm trying to add strings into an array, then print that list as a "guest list" for a party. Right now, my addGuest method compiles, but when I run the driver program, nothing is printed, meaning the addGuest isn't functioning right.

```
public class Party
{
   private static int maxGuests;
   private static int numGuests;
   private static String[] guestNames = new String[maxGuests];
   private static String hostName;

   public Party(int maxGuests, String hostName)
   {
      this.hostName = hostName;
      this.maxGuests = maxGuests;
   }

   public static void addGuest(String guestName)
   {
      if(isOnList(guestName) == true)
      {
         System.out.println(guestName + " is already on the list");
      }
      else if(maxGuests == guestNames.length)
      {
         System.out.println(guestName + " could not be added because the 
         party is full");
      }
      else if(isOnList(guestName) == false)
      {
         for(int i = 0; i < guestNames.length; i++)
         {
            guestNames[i] = guestName;
         }
      }

   }

   public static boolean isOnList(String guestName)
   {
      boolean onList = false;
      for(int i = 0; i < guestNames.length; i++)
      {
         if(guestNames[i].length() <= 1)
         {
            onList = false;
         }
         else if(guestNames[i].compareTo(guestName) == 0)
            onList = true;
      }
      return onList;
   }

   public static void printParty()
   {
      System.out.println("Guest list for " + hostName + "'s party: ");
      for(String name : guestNames)
      {
         System.out.println(name);
      }


Public static void main(String[] args){
Party party = new Party(3, "David Beckham");
      //Party.addGuest("Roberto Baggio");
      Party.addGuest("Zinedine Zidane");
      Party.addGuest("Roberto Baggio");
      Party.addGuest("Johan Cruyff");
      Party.addGuest("Diego Maradona");
      Party.printParty();
}
```

I expected it to print the first 3 names, as thats the party size, then print the associated error message for when the party is full, but instead, nothing is printed besides "The guest list for David Beckham's party: "

Comment: `Public` static void main? (Emphasis on the capital `P`) You're also missing a closing brace

Comment: Your fields are static, yet you are creating a `Party` object. This is all so confusing.

Comment: Also in your add method, if the list doesn't contain the name, you set every index of the array to the new name

Comment: But `guestName` is the method parameter, it has precedence over `this.guestName`.

Comment: I would highly recommend going through this by hand and/or your debugger to test the logic and to see what is going on

Comment: Since `String[] guestNames` is initialized before constructor invocation, its length is always 0.

Comment: @ Ricky Mo in this case text message is supposed to be shown

Comment: I also recommend looking up what the `static` keyword means/does. You are using it incorrectly here

Comment: @KenBekov should it not then print the error message? Allegedly nothing is being printed.

Comment: @Gendarme KenBekov is right. Note the last `else{}` block is missing. If the array is 0 length, nothing will be executed.

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot that `maxGuests` is set to `3`. Thought it was `0` as well.

Comment: @KenBekov how do I fix that then if I need to refer to guestNames in all of my methods? If yoou guys couldn't tell, I'm a first year CSA student. Note--A restriction I have is that guestNames has to be an instance variable that stores names of all people on the guest list

Comment: @KenBekov analysis is correct. One way is to have a DEFAULT_MAX_GUESTS and then also initialize them with null. Also remove/modify the check "guestNames[i].length() <= 1" to either " guestNames[i] != null && guestNames[i].isEmpty()

Comment: A good first step is to remove `static` from all your class members (except `main`), @CS2020, and fix your typographical mistakes. As Ken Bekov points out, do `this.guestNames = new String[maxGuests]` inside the constructor instead.. Then take it from there, one thing at a time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class Party
{
   private static int maxGuests;
   private static int numGuests = 0;
   private static String[] guestNames;
   private static String hostName;

   public Party(int maxGuests, String hostName)
   {
      this.hostName = hostName;
      this.maxGuests = maxGuests;
      this.guestNames = new String[maxGuests + 1];
   }

   public static void addGuest(String guestName)
   {
      if(isOnList(guestName) == true)
      {
         System.out.println(guestName + " is already on the list");
      }
      else if(maxGuests < numGuests)
      {
         System.out.println(guestName + " could not be added because the party is full");
      }
      else if(isOnList(guestName) == false)
      {
        guestNames[numGuests] = guestName;
        numGuests++;
      }

   }

   public static boolean isOnList(String guestName)
   {
      boolean onList = false;
      for(int i = 0; i < guestNames.length; i++)
      {
         if(guestNames[i] != null && guestNames[i].length() <= 1)
         {
            onList = false;
         }
         else if(guestNames[i] != null && guestNames[i].compareTo(guestName) == 0)
         {
            onList = true;
         }      
      }
      return onList;
   }

   public static void printParty()
   {
      System.out.println("Guest list for " + hostName + "'s party: ");
      for(String name : guestNames)
      {
         System.out.println(name);
      }
   }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Party party = new Party(3, "David Beckham");
        Party.addGuest("Zinedine Zidane");
        Party.addGuest("Roberto Baggio");
        Party.addGuest("Johan Cruyff");
        Party.addGuest("Diego Maradona");
        Party.printParty();
    }
}
```

The above code works as per your requirement

1) First you have set the array size to zero during start

2) The way you are trying to store values to array is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a good start, but you have several problems going on here. First, there's a big difference between [class methods and variables](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/glossary-135216.html#cmethod) and [instance methods and variables](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/glossary-135216.html#imethod). Study the definitions and look at examples to obtain a good understanding. This will help you a lot.

Based on the code you have provided I'm guessing you're trying to write instance methods and variables. Therefore you should remove the `static` keyword from all of your methods and variables **except** for the `main` method which is always `static`.

Next, you need to be careful about how you initialize your variables. Initializing your array outside of the constructor before the maximum size is known will cause the size to be 0.

There are also some logical errors in your program. For example on this line:

`else if(maxGuests == guestNames.length)`

The maxGuests is used as the size of the array so this is always going to result in `true`. You want to keep track of the number of guests as you add them and use that value to compare with the maximum.

e.g. `else if (maxGuests == numGuests)`

Inside of this next condition you have a problem as well:

```
      else if(isOnList(guestName) == false)
      {
         for(int i = 0; i < guestNames.length; i++)
         {
            guestNames[i] = guestName;
         }
      }
```

You are overwriting all the guest names with the name of the guest you're currently adding by using a loop here. Just remove the loop and use the number of guests (`numGuests`) to insert the new guest. Then increment the number of guests.

```
guestNames[numGuests] = guestName;  
numGuests++;
```

Since your `addGuest` method calls your `isOnList` method it is possible that no guests have been added to the array yet. This means the array has no value (i.e. `null`) for each index. In this scenario your logic `if(guestNames[i].length() <= 1)` will fail with a `NullPointerException` because you can't call `.length()` on a `null`. You need to add a check for `null` here like this:

`if (guestNames[i] == null || guestNames[i].length() <= 1)`

Finally, in your `main` method you need to change the way you call your methods from the static way (referring directly to the class) to the instance way (referring to the object). Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Party party = new Party(3, "David Beckham");
    party.addGuest("Zinedine Zidane");
    party.addGuest("Roberto Baggio");
    party.addGuest("Johan Cruyff");
    party.addGuest("Diego Maradona");
    party.printParty();
}
```

Here is the complete code with these issues fixed:

```
public class Party {

    private int maxGuests;
    private int numGuests = 0;
    private String[] guestNames;
    private String hostName;

    public Party(int maxGuests, String hostName) {
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.maxGuests = maxGuests;
        guestNames = new String[maxGuests];
    }

    public void addGuest(String guestName) {
        if (isOnList(guestName) == true) {
            System.out.println(guestName + " is already on the list");
        } else if (maxGuests == numGuests) {
            System.out.println(guestName + " could not be added because the party is full");
        } else if (isOnList(guestName) == false) {
                guestNames[numGuests] = guestName;  
                numGuests++;
        }

    }

    public boolean isOnList(String guestName) {
        boolean onList = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < guestNames.length; i++) {
            if (guestNames[i] == null || guestNames[i].length() <= 1) {
                onList = false;
            } else if (guestNames[i].compareTo(guestName) == 0)
                onList = true;
        }
        return onList;
    }

    public void printParty() {
        System.out.println("Guest list for " + hostName + "'s party: ");
        for (String name : guestNames) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Party party = new Party(3, "David Beckham");
        party.addGuest("Zinedine Zidane");
        party.addGuest("Roberto Baggio");
        party.addGuest("Johan Cruyff");
        party.addGuest("Diego Maradona");
        party.printParty();
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
Diego Maradona could not be added because the party is full
Guest list for David Beckham's party: 
Zinedine Zidane
Roberto Baggio
Johan Cruyff
```

Hope this helps!

As a final thought - you might want to take a look through some of the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/) to become more familiar with important aspects of Java and of Object Oriented Programming in general.

Answer (score -1):

Your fields are declared as `static`. This means that the reference these variables refers remain the same for all `Party` instance and they are initialized before calling a constructor.

Since the values are initialized before the `new Party(3, "David")` call, the value the `guestNames` array will be a zero-sized String array.

Now, looking at you if/else ladder, the only condition that will be satisfied is the last `else if (isOnList(guestName) == false)`. Since the `guestNames.length` is `0`, the code inside the `for` loop will not execute.

Comment: How does this explain the fact that his `addGuest` method isn't working as intended?

Comment: The array, `guestNames` is set to `new String[0]` (because `maxGuests` is `0` by the time the array is declared. With this, and given how the if/else statements are written, the `guestNames` will never have itself filled.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve same result by following way(alternative way).

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Party party = new Party(3, "David Beckham");
        party.addGuest("Zinedine Zidane");
        party.addGuest("Roberto Baggio");
        party.addGuest("Johan Cruyff");
        party.addGuest("Diego Maradona");
        party.printParty();
    }
}


public class Party {
    private int maxGuests;
    private String hostName;

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public Party(int maxGuests, String hostName) {
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.maxGuests = maxGuests;
    }
    public void addGuest(String guestName) {
        if (isOnList(guestName) == true) {
            System.out.println(guestName + " is already on the list");
        } else if (maxGuests == list.size()) {
            System.out.println(guestName + " could not be added because the        party is full");
        } else if (isOnList(guestName) == false) {
            list.add(guestName);
        }
    }

    public boolean isOnList(String guestName) {
        return list.contains(guestName);
    }
    public void printParty() {
        System.out.println("Guest list for " + hostName + "'s party: ");
        for (String name : list) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```